# SQL Execute one query of 2 based on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 working query that I need to use to generate a report, I have configured 4 parameters that user can choose and I want that if idarea=0 then first query is executed, else second one. I tried the following but give me an error because of the nested with... any help? Thanks

```
declare @DataDa as date='20210501';
declare @DataA as date='20210504';
declare @idUtilizzatore as int=0;
declare @idArea as int=0;
SELECT CASE WHEN ( @idArea=0 )
    THEN (select dbaree.dbo.StoricoAree.Descr as Lettore,
                                TIMBACCESSI.CODICEBADGE,
                                COGNOME as Cognome,NOME as Nome,
                                AZIENDE.DESCR as Azienda,FORMAT(DATAORA,'HH:mm') as Ora,
                                FORMAT(dataora,'dd/MM/yyyy') as Data, 
                                iif(verso=0,'U','E') as Flusso from timbaccessi 
                                join badge on badge.codice=timbaccessi.codicebadge 
                                join anagrafico on anagrafico.ID=badge.IDUTILIZZATORE 
                                join profilo on profilo.IDUTILIZZATORE=badge.IDUTILIZZATORE 
                                join aziende on aziende.id=profilo.IDAZIENDA 
                                join terminali on terminali.id=TIMBACCESSI.IDTERMINALE 
                                join comparee on terminali.id=COMPAREE.IDTERMINALE 
                                join dbAree.dbo.StoricoAree on storicoaree.idArea=COMPAREE.IDAREA 
                                where (DATAORA>=@DataDa and DATAORA<@DataA) and (DATAORA >= dataDa and(DATAORA <= dataA or dataa is null)) and (badge.DATAFINE is null or badge.DATAFINE>=@DataA) AND (badge.idUtilizzatore = @IdUtilizzatore OR 0 = @IdUtilizzatore) AND (PROFILO.IDAZIENDA=@idAzienda OR 0 = @idAzienda) and (dbaree.dbo.StoricoAree.id=@idArea OR 0=@idArea)
                                group by dataora,cognome,nome,dbaree.dbo.StoricoAree.Descr,timbaccessi.CODICEBADGE,aziende.DESCR,timbaccessi.VERSO
                                ORDER BY Azienda asc, cognome asc, nome asc, Data asc, ora asc)
    ELSE (with area as(


                                select t.CODICEBADGE as 'Numero tessera',
                                COGNOME as Cognome,NOME as Nome,
                                AZIENDE.DESCR as Azienda,FORMAT(DATAORA,'HH:mm') as Ora,
                                FORMAT(dataora,'dd/MM/yyyy') as Data, 
                                iif(verso=0,'U','E') as Flusso, t.IDTERMINALE,t.DATAORA from timbaccessi t 
                                join badge on badge.codice=t.codicebadge 
                                join anagrafico on anagrafico.ID=badge.IDUTILIZZATORE 
                                join profilo on profilo.IDUTILIZZATORE=badge.IDUTILIZZATORE 
                                join aziende on aziende.id=profilo.IDAZIENDA 
                                join terminali on terminali.id=t.IDTERMINALE 
                                where (DATAORA>=@DataDa and DATAORA<@DataA) 
                                and (badge.DATAFINE is null or badge.DATAFINE>=@DataA) AND (badge.idUtilizzatore = @IdUtilizzatore OR 0 = @IdUtilizzatore)
                                group by dataora,cognome,nome,t.CODICEBADGE,aziende.DESCR,t.VERSO,t.IDTERMINALE)
                                select a.[Numero tessera],a.Cognome,a.Nome,a.Azienda,a.Ora,a.Data,a.Flusso,s.Descr from area a join dbAree.dbo.StoricoAree s on s.id=@idArea where a.IDTERMINALE in (select idterminale from dbAree.dbo.termArea t join dbaree.dbo.StoricoAree s on s.id=t.idArea where t.idArea=@idArea and (@DataDa >= s.datada and (s.dataA is null or @DataDa < s.dataA))) 
                                order by a.DATAORA )
END;
```

Comment: `CASE` is an expression that returns a **scalar** value. Having a subquery that returns multiple columns and rows makes no sense. Perhaps you want an `IF`?

Comment: Also [3+ part naming on Columns will be Deprecated](https://wp.larnu.uk/3-part-naming-on-columns-will-be-deprecated/). Stick to aliasing your objects and using those for qualifying your columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `IF`:

```
IF (@idArea = 0)
BEGIN
    <query1>;
END;
ELSE 
    <query 2>;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another way besides `if` that I've found useful.  You can use `union all` and appropriately filter in your `where` statements.

It only makes sense when your output columns are the same number, order, and type.  In your case, that's not true, but a very small modification can make it so:

```
declare @DataDa as date='20210501';
declare @DataA as date='20210504';
declare @idUtilizzatore as int=0;
declare @idArea as int=0;

with area as(

    select      t.CODICEBADGE as 'Numero tessera',
                COGNOME as Cognome,NOME as Nome,
                AZIENDE.DESCR as Azienda,
                FORMAT(DATAORA,'HH:mm') as Ora,
                FORMAT(dataora,'dd/MM/yyyy') as Data, 
                iif(verso=0,'U','E') as Flusso, 
                t.IDTERMINALE,t.DATAORA 
    from        timbaccessi t 
    join        badge on badge.codice=t.codicebadge 
    join        anagrafico on anagrafico.ID=badge.IDUTILIZZATORE 
    join        profilo on profilo.IDUTILIZZATORE=badge.IDUTILIZZATORE 
    join        aziende on aziende.id=profilo.IDAZIENDA 
    join        terminali on terminali.id=t.IDTERMINALE 
    where       (DATAORA>=@DataDa and DATAORA<@DataA) 
    and         (badge.DATAFINE is null or badge.DATAFINE>=@DataA) 
    AND         (badge.idUtilizzatore = @IdUtilizzatore OR 0 = @IdUtilizzatore)
    group by    dataora,cognome,nome,t.CODICEBADGE,aziende.DESCR,t.VERSO,t.IDTERMINALE
                            
)

select      dbaree.dbo.StoricoAree.Descr as Lettore,
            TIMBACCESSI.CODICEBADGE,
            null as [Numero tessera], // not relevant unless @idArea <> 0
            COGNOME as Cognome,
            NOME as Nome,
            AZIENDE.DESCR as Azienda,
            FORMAT(DATAORA,'HH:mm') as Ora,
            FORMAT(dataora,'dd/MM/yyyy') as Data, 
            iif(verso=0,'U','E') as Flusso,
            null as Desc // not relevant unless @idArea <> 0
from        timbaccessi 
join        badge on badge.codice=timbaccessi.codicebadge 
join        anagrafico on anagrafico.ID=badge.IDUTILIZZATORE 
join        profilo on profilo.IDUTILIZZATORE=badge.IDUTILIZZATORE 
join        aziende on aziende.id=profilo.IDAZIENDA 
join        terminali on terminali.id=TIMBACCESSI.IDTERMINALE 
join        comparee on terminali.id=COMPAREE.IDTERMINALE 
join        dbAree.dbo.StoricoAree on storicoaree.idArea=COMPAREE.IDAREA 
where       (DATAORA>=@DataDa and DATAORA<@DataA) 
and         (DATAORA >= dataDa and(DATAORA <= dataA or dataa is null)) 
and         (badge.DATAFINE is null or badge.DATAFINE>=@DataA) 
AND         (badge.idUtilizzatore = @IdUtilizzatore OR 0 = @IdUtilizzatore) 
AND         (PROFILO.IDAZIENDA=@idAzienda OR 0 = @idAzienda) 
and         (dbaree.dbo.StoricoAree.id=@idArea OR 0=@idArea)
and         @idArea = 0 // your case ////////////////////////////////////////
group by    dataora,cognome,nome,dbaree.dbo.StoricoAree.Descr,
            timbaccessi.CODICEBADGE,aziende.DESCR,timbaccessi.VERSO

union all 
select      null as Lettore, // not relevant unless @idArea = 0
            null as CODICEBADGE, // not relevant unless @idArea = 0
            a.Cognome,
            a.Nome,
            a.Azienda,
            a.Ora,
            a.Data,
            a.Flusso,
            s.Descr 
from        area a 
join        dbAree.dbo.StoricoAree s on s.id=@idArea 
where       a.IDTERMINALE in (
                select      idterminale 
                from        dbAree.dbo.termArea t 
                join        dbaree.dbo.StoricoAree s on s.id=t.idArea 
                where       t.idArea=@idArea 
                and         (
                                @DataDa >= s.datada and 
                                (s.dataA is null or @DataDa < s.dataA)
                            ) 
                order by    a.DATAORA 
            )
and         (@idArea <> 0 or @idArea is null) // your else /////////////////

ORDER BY    Azienda asc, cognome asc, nome asc, Data asc, ora asc;
```

This has the advantage of keeping the result set predictable.  If it's predictable, it can have some advantages.  For instance, if desired, you could turn this into a table valued function.  Or you could otherwise have other code that depends on it and won't break if the output has an unexpected structure.